# Run callback with all arguments

Tags: javascript, callback

How can I run a callback function with all of its arguments when I don't know how many arguments are supplied.

Take the following example:

```
function tryMe (param1, param2) {
    alert(param1 + " and " + param2);
}

function callbackTester (callback) {
    callback (arguments[1], arguments[2]);
}

callbackTester (tryMe, "hello", "goodbye");

callbackTester (tryMe, "hello", "goodbye", "seeYouLater");
```

How can I run the callback from the `callbackTester()` function so that it will automatically call all of its arguments?

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/qj1rs29q/

Comment: if you don't know how many arguments there are, how would you know what each of the arguments is supposed to be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This one should suit your needs:

```
function callbackTester() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
        callback = args.shift();
    callback.apply(this, args);
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qj1rs29q/2/)

Answer (score 1):

ECMAScript6 introduces the so called [**rest parameter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters). It lets you refer to all remaining arguments that are not explicitly listed. Together with [**`.apply`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), your function will look like

```
function callbackTester (callback, ...args) {
    callback.apply(null, args);
}

// callback = tryme | args = ["hello", "goodbye"]
callbackTester(tryMe, "hello", "goodbye");
```

You can use ES6 features today with transpilers such as [6to5](https://6to5.org/).